# "Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this error:

> Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

with inner exception:

> Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.

Any idea why this happening?

Incidentally, the error is happening on this line:

```
@Html.Action("Menu", "Navigation")
```

The Menu Action in the Navigation Controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Menu()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: You may look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056421/why-are-redirect-results-not-allowed-in-child-actions-in-asp-net-mvc-2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not allowed because MVC has already started Rendering the View to the browser (client).
So the MVC Frameworks blocks this, because the client already receives data (html). As long as the rendering is in progress you not able to redirect in your child view.

You can return `RedirectToAction` instead.

Comment: I tried so many solutions to get a custom auth filter working and finally figured out that my view was calling `@Html.Action()` instead of `@Url.Action()` the latter gives you a url for a link and the former executes a controller action rendering it's view in place. Very frustrating, make sure you aren't making this mistake

Comment: I am using RedirectToAction in my controller, but it still gives me the error

Answer (score 12):

This happened to me because I had [RequireHttps] on the Controller, and a child action was called from a different controller.   The RequireHttps attribute caused the redirect

Comment: In my case it wasn't actually `[RequireHttps]`, but another (custom) attribute which also happens to do some redirecting.  This answer got me thinking about the right thing though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Instead of `@Html` use `@Url`.

Before: `@Html.Action("Menu", "Navigation")`

After: `@Url.Action("Menu", "Navigation")`

Answer (score 1):

> I had same situation like Doug described above

My solution:
1)Created custom Controller Factory. It's need for getting ControllerContext in my custom https attribute.

```
public class CustomControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            var controller = base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
            HttpContext.Current.Items["controllerInstance"] = controller;
            return controller;
        }
    }
}
```

2)In Application_Start function from Global.asax file wrote next:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new CustomControllerFactory());
```

3)Defined custom https attribute:

```
public class CustomRequireHttpsAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.RequireHttpsAttribute
    {
        public bool RequireSecure = false;

        public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {

            if (RequireSecure && !((Controller)HttpContext.Current.Items["controllerInstance"]).ControllerContext.IsChildAction)
            {
                base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            }
        }        
    }
```

4)Using new attribute for definition of account controller:
 `[CustomRequireHttps]`

Answer (score 0):

redirect like this

```
string returnUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
return Redirect(returnUrl);
```

instead of

```
return redirect("Action","Controller")
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the  [NoDirectAccess] annotation if added in the controller.

and in controller for the partial view

return PartialView() instead of return View()

Answer (score 0):

This happens in cases where the Action called by the Html.Action performs a redirection such as

```
return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
```

instead of returning the desired `partialView`

So the solution would be to remove the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be thrown when the page being called has a @model directive that cannot be resolved.

```
﻿Ex: 'Management.ViewModels.Utilities.SomeExampleVM' -> 'Management.SharedLibrary.Compatibilty.Utilities.SomeExampleVM'
```

We have multiple developers on a project and had an individual make this change and then miss updating the reference on the page. OPs error was thrown. Redirecting the page's model call to the new location resolved the error.