# MVC3 Wrong form submits

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, forms

From every page of a website I'm making, you're able to sign in. On pages with other forms, I get the following error after submitting: "Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions." All forms worked fine until I added the Sign In. In addition, the Sign In works correctly when you use it. The error only appears if I submit a different form. I've set a breakpoint and I've watched what happens when I hit the other submit. For some reason, the SignIn Post ActionResult is trying to run.
Any help would be appreciated.

#### Error:

> Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions. Line 67: @{Html.RenderAction("SignIn", "Account");}

#### Sign In View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SignIn", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input class="signInSubmit" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="" />
}
```

#### Another Form in View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Confirm", "Cart", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "productDetailsForm" }))
{
    <input class="addToCart" type="submit" name="submit" value="" />
}
```

#### Sign In Controller

```
// GET: /Account/SignIn
public ActionResult SignIn()
{
    return PartialView();
}

// POST: /Account/SignIn
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SignIn(Customer customer)
{
    try
    {
        //Stuff is here
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    catch
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Registration");
    }
}
```

#### Other form Controller

```
// GET: /Cart/
public ActionResult Index()
{
  CartViewModel cart = getCart();
  return View(cart);
}

//POST: Cart/Confirm
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Confirm(int productID, bool certs, int quantity)
{
  CartItemViewModel viewModel = new CartItemViewModel
  {
    Item = productRep.GetProductByID(productID),
    Certs = certs,
    Quantity = quantity
  };
  return View(viewModel);
}
```

#### HTML Source Code

```
<form action="/Account/SignIn" method="post">
    <input class="signInSubmit" type="submit" value="" />
</form>
<form action="/Cart/Confirm" id="productDetailsForm" method="post">
    <input class="addToCart" type="submit" value="" />
</form>
```

Comment: maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924529/mvc-3-error-child-actions-are-not-allowed-to-perform-redirect-actions

Comment: I read it, unfortunately it didn't help. Thanks for trying though; I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### My solution

I renamed the POST ActionResult to anything other than SignIn. Does anyone understand why this works?

#### AccountController

```
// POST: /Account/Signed
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Signed(Customer customer)
{
    try
    {
        //Stuff is here
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    catch
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Registration");
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you return with RedirectToAction instead PartialView?