# Error: Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I used asp.net mvc 5. The action method is:

```
public ActionResult GetRSSFeed(string  rssfeed, string xslt)
{
    try
    {
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(rssfeed);
        string returnhtml = ConvertXML(xDoc, Server.MapPath(xslt), new XsltArgumentList());
        //InsertArticlesInDatabase(returnhtml);
        return Content(returnhtml.
            Replace(@"[[ This is a content summary only. Visit my website for full links, other content, and more! ]]",
            ""));
    }
    catch
    {
        return Content("");
    }
}
```

The code in view is:

```
Html.Action("GetRSSFeed", "RSSReader", new { rssfeed = Model.RssFeed.ToString(),xslt = Url.Content(Model.XsltTransformation.ToString()), area = "RSSReader" })
```

When exception is appear the execution does not go in the code in controller.

How can I fix this error, and why that error appear? The code in controller does not redirect anywhere, it just return pure html.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924529/child-actions-are-not-allowed-to-perform-redirect-actions)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be a repeat of this:
[Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015833/child-actions-are-not-allowed-to-perform-redirect-actions-after-setting-the-sit)

This happened to mea few times because I had [RequireHttps] on the Controller, and a child action was called from a different controller. The RequireHttps attribute caused the redirect