# MVC: proper authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

In my controller I have a login method. There I check credentials and if everything is ok call

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
```

It works but if I immediately check

```
this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

inside a controller I see that it is still false. I need to refresh a page to see that user is indeed authenticated. Is there a possibility to make user authenticated immediately, during the same request? Other partial views which are rendered after depend on it.

In web forms development I would call something like

```
RedirectFromLoginPage
```

but here it is inside partial view rendered from a layout file, I can't redirect from there.

Comment: Why can't you redirect? You are inside a controller method. You should be able to return `RedirectToAction()`

Comment: My logon view is a partial view being rendered inside layout file. I tried to do RedirectToAction() but get an exception. Can't check it this very moment, maybe it was "Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions".

Comment: That means, you login action is called by RenderAction? Can't you just  post your login form to a standard action method?

Comment: I'm new to mvc as you have probably already realized :-) So it is a bit hard for me to answer your question. I have _layout.cshtml file which needs to contain logon controls shown on the top of every page (or logged in user name). Inside _layout.cshtml I call
    @Html.Action("LogOn", "Account")
it's not RenderAction.

Comment: Ok, the LogOn action renders a LogOn view with the login form, right? Now tell me, how that LogOn view calls the action where you call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`?

Comment: <input type="submit" ...
Posting.

Comment: Can you show more code? At least the view with your login form and the action method that gets called? I don't see a partial action here.

Comment: Ok, in a controller there is a method 

    ActionResult LogOn()

which returns a view as usual. And another one 

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)

which receives posted information and performs logon. returnUrl is not used now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);` sets an encrypted authentication cookie.  Because this is a cookie, the call for `IsAuthenticated` is not immediate as the user has to make another request to the server in order for the cookie to be sent to/from the client.

Comment: Good explanation, but no solution proposed :-)

Comment: You have to redirect from your HTTPPOST login action.  Not from inside the view.  There is no option to 'authenticate the user immediately'

Comment: This answer helped me to resolve a pb: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5444079/1025581
Your answer is obviously true so I mark it.