# Redirection error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Taking first steps with ASP.NET MVC, I am trying to create a simple (and typical) article-with-comments page: under an article itself there should be a form enabling an user to post a comment to the article.

I created a partial view for the submit form and `CommentController` with following methods:

```
public ActionResult Add(int entryId);

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Comment comment);
```

Then, under the article in a view of `HomeController`:

```
<div class="add-comment">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("Add", "Comment", new { entryId = Model.EntryId }); }
</div>
```

The form renders properly and the adding procedure actually works (comment gets saved into database), but after redirecting back to the article     `InvalidOperationException` is thrown, with `Html.RenderAction` (the one shown above) highlited in debugger:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.

Why does it happen?

Here's the code for `CommentController` methods:

```
public ActionResult Add(int entryId)
{
    var comment = new Comment { EntryId = entryId };
    return PartialView(comment);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Comment comment)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        comment.Date = DateTime.Now;
        var entry = db.Entries.FirstOrDefault(e => e.EntryId == comment.EntryId);
        if (entry != null)
        {
            entry.Comments.Add(comment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Show", "Home", new { id = entry.EntryId });
        }
    }

    return PartialView(comment);
}
```

Or maybe should I even take a diffrent approach?

Comment: This answer probably has an explenation. I see that I have upvoted it at some point so it has helped me at least :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056421/why-are-redirect-results-not-allowed-in-child-actions-in-asp-net-mvc-2

Comment: Where is the action method of getting comments from database ?

Comment: There is none. Model class passed to view (action Show) has a collection of comments as a navigation property, so displaying them wasn't a problem.

Comment: @Doe, could you add the code for the `Show` action of the `Home` controller? Also, could you post the stack trace for the error? It might tell us in which controller is the error happening.

Comment: @Doe You can't use return RedirectToAction("Show", "Home", new { id = entry.EntryId }); because you are in ChildAction, this is the problem. This logic should not be in child action, should be in parent.

Comment: @AlbertoLeón, the OP seems to be following the standard Post-Redirect-Get pattern. The `RedirectToAction` is needed here.

Answer (score 0):

Add `HttpGet` on the other Add action

Comment: It hasn't really changed anything. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

You should/could be using `RenderPartial` instead of `RenderAction`:

```
Html.RenderPartial("YourPartialView", new Comment { EntryId = Model.EntryId });
```

There appears to be no need to use your action method if all you are doing is instantiating a model that you already have the ID too.