# MVC Route return Error : Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am using nopCommmerce 3.40 , MVC 5

I have make plugin and make route one route for action

But i am getting error look like :

```
Error executing child request for handler'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions
```

My Code

```
[AdminAuthorize]
    public ActionResult Configure()
    {

       return RedirectToRoute("PluginName.ActionName");
    }

    public ActionResult ActionName()
    {
       // i want to call/ return this  from Configure mathod
    }
```

RouteProvider

```
routes.MapRoute("PluginName.ActionName", "Admin/Plugins",
                     new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action" },
                     new[] { "PluginName.ActionName.Controllers" }
                     ).DataTokens.Add("area", "admin");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you get says it all. You cannot perform a redirection there. Plugin configure actions are, in fact, invoked using child actions and, therefore, are usually decorated with the [ChildActionOnly] attribute. You can find a more detailed message at this answer [Why are Redirect Results not allowed in Child Actions in Asp.net MVC 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056421/why-are-redirect-results-not-allowed-in-child-actions-in-asp-net-mvc-2).

You should refactor your code to call the redirection from some other place like the main action or a custom action filter applied to the main action, for instance.

But, since the code that calls your Configure action is out of your control because it belongs to nopCommerce, not to your plugin, your best shot is to inject a custom action filter dynamically and perform the redirection there.